Safetensor to GGUF (with llama vision)
I’ve started exploring the world of local LLMs. I’m using Ollama as my server and wanted to use this model: huihui-ai/Llama-3.2-11B-Vision-Instruct-abliterate.
I downloaded the model and tried converting it to GGUF format using the convert-hf-to-gguf.py script from llama.cpp, but I encountered an issue. The script gives me this error:
Model MllamaForConditionalGeneration is not supported.


What I’ve Tried:

Using Ollama’s built-in converter:

The process failed, but no detailed error message was provided.


Using the convert-hf-to-gguf.py script from llama.cpp:

It threw the above error (Model MllamaForConditionalGeneration is not supported.).




What I’m Unsure About:

Is this issue specific to the model itself?
Are there compatibility issues with the tools I’m using (Ollama or llama.cpp)?
Is there a different workflow or set of tools I should consider for converting this model?


Additional Context:

I found a similar thread about LLaVA, but the error is different, so I’m not sure if I can follow the same steps.

